# fakeroot debian/rules binary error

Tags: dpkg, deb, packaging, debian, makefile

I have a package I'm maintaining. When I issue "fakeroot debian/rules binary" I get this error:

```
dh_install --sourcedir=debian/tmp 
cp: cannot stat `debian/tmp/usr/share/prg/1.svg': No such file or directory 
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/usr/share/prg/1.svg debian/prg//usr/share/prg/ returned exit code 1 
make: * [install-arch] Error 2
```

I am unable to rectify this error. I can issue "cd debian/tmp/usr/share/prg" then "ls" and voila the 1.svg actually does exist.

In my makefile:

```
dist_pkgdata_DATA = 1.svg
```

And in my prg.install file:

```
usr/share/prg/1.svg
etc/config.ini
```

The config.ini file has no issue installing.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being thrown by `dh_install`, as invoked by your `debian/rules` file.  It's most likely the *destination* that is missing, not the source file. In this case, does `debian/prg//usr/share/prg` exist? I'd wager not.  Conventionally, the files for a package are built up either in `debian/tmp` (typical for 1:1 source:binary packages) or `debian/binary-package-name` (better for 1:n source:binary packages), so trying to copy from one convention to another suggests an error.

Check your `debian/*install` file(s). see also the `dh_install(1)` manpage.  In particular,

> debian/package.install
>
> > List the files to install into each package and the directory they
> >     should be installed to. The format is a set of lines, where each
> >     line lists a file or files to install, and at the end of the line
> >     tells the directory it should be installed in. The name of the
> >     files (or directories) to install should be given relative to the
> >     current directory, while **the installation directory is given
> >     relative to the package build directory**. You may use wildcards in
> >     the names of the files to install (in v3 mode and above).

If you really want `debian/prg/usr/share/prg` to exist, you must instruct `dh_installdirs` to create the directories.  Create `debian/package.dirs` for your package, listing the names of directories to create, relative to the build directory, e.g.

```
usr/share/man/man6
usr/lib
usr/share/prg
```

Comment: debian/prg//usr/share/prg does exist. But debian/prg//usr/share/prg/1.svg doesn't exist...

I tried to instruct dh_installdirs to create the directories, but still the same error.